# Deploy java-application on tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I have developed a java webservice application that I have been running on my dev-computer and in the meanwhile been setting up a dedicated ubuntu based linux server.
I have installed oracle-jre, mysql and apache tomcat 7 on this linux server and
after reading documentation I understand that I can either copy the deployed project archive (.WAR) or I can simply copy the project folder, into the servers /webapps/ folder from my development computer. Then restart tomcat7 and it should automatically run the webapp.

On my dev-computer with Eclipse IDE the webservice works properly as expected, but I cannot access the POST URL methods at all on the server
e.g. localhost:8080/Webservice/rest/account/login
(The installation on the server seems to be O.K as the Apache examples all work properly.)

1. I cannot see any logs in the /logs/ directory, in fact the folder is completely empty, so I cannot debug whats actually happening. Why aren't logs writing to the Catalina.out file?
2. Am I deploying this correctly as explained above?
3. Do I need to configure Eclipse or any project settings to reflect the change from the eclipse IDE / dev-computer to the server? E.g Is there any real difference?

A lot of questions there, but I wanted to clarify as much as possible,
Cheers,
Oliver

Comment: Dear friend, where do you copy your WAR file ?

Comment: Hopefully you run under the same user as the one you used to install the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling tomcat.